# Is there a way to force an AVPlayer audio stream to always play live with limited buffering?

Tags: iphone, xcode, audio-streaming, avplayer, internet-radio

I am creating an app that will stream audio live from an internet radio stream.

I am using AVPLayer and create an AVAudioSession, etc, etc...

Everything works fine, except... there is no [stop] function with AVPlayer, only [play] and [pause].  So when a user pauses the stream, it buffers and when they click play, it starts where it left off when they pressed pause before.

The question... Is there a way to force the audio stream to always play live?

I really don't want any buffering more than a few seconds...

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want buffering then try to play streaming live audio via MPMovieviewcontroller.

It is perfect player for live streaming audio/video. I am also use this player in one of my

App for play live audio streaming. I think your all requirement match with this. Try to imple

ment it. It is easy to implement also.Here is my code to play stream audio using

MPMovieviewcontroller:

```
    NSURL *fileURL=[NSURL URLWithString:geturl];
    NSLog(@"fileURL..%@",fileURL);
    moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
    [moviePlayerController.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
    moviePlayerController.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay=YES;
    moviePlayerController.view.frame = self.view.frame;
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayerController];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreen:) name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification object:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
    [moviePlayerController.moviePlayer play];

- (void)MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreen:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification 
                                                  object:nil];

    [moviePlayerController.moviePlayer stop];
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [notification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
     removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
     object:player];
    [moviePlayerController dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated];
}
```

And for background playing I add these lines in my info.plist. You also add these to plist:

[image]

Comment: Vishal, thank you for your suggestion.  Do you have any sample code so I could see how you implemented this?  The Apple documentation talks alot about video and the view for the video.  I just need audio to play in the background.  Thank you!

Comment: I edit my above answer see how I play stream audio using MPMovieviewcontroller...

Comment: Also make appropriate property of MPmovieviecontroller in .h file and add it #import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h> in .m file...